# Can @ApplicationPath annotation be used on interface?

Tags: java, jax-rs

According to JAXRS spec, is @ApplicationPath can be used on interface?

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public interface TestRes {

}
```

Compiler dont have a problem with that. But is this good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ApplicationPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) Documentation cleary says it is only applicable for `subclass` of `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` so if you apply on the interface it will not work, so when you deploy you might end up with this error message `The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes."`

> Identifies the application path that serves as the base URI for all resource URIs provided by Path.**May only be applied to a subclass of Application.**

[jaxrs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm)

> The @ApplicationPath annotation is used to define the URL mapping for the application. The path specified by @ApplicationPath is the base URI for all resource URIs specified by @Path annotations in the resource class. **You may only apply @ApplicationPath to a subclass of javax.ws.rs.core.Application.**

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to extend `Application` so it can't be used on an interface.